# how to find order of arbitary elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If we have for example $U(15)=\{1,2,4,7,8,11,13,14\}$ in $\times _{15}$, to find the order of say $7$ would be to do:

$7=7 \neq 1$,

$7^2=49=4 \neq 1$,

$7^3=13 \neq 1$,

$7^4=2401=1$ so the order of $7$ is $4$.

If we have $C_{12}=\{1,a,a^2,...,a^{11}\}$, how do we find say the order of $a^2$? Or any other element.

Comment: Just to be sure, your object of interest is
$$\mathbb Z_{15}^\times = \{ a \in \mathbb Z_{15} \mid \gcd(a,15) = 1 \}$$
with multiplication modulo $15$ as the group operation, right?

Comment: not too sure. for 7^4=2041, if you keep minusing 15, you will get 1. not too sure about gcd

Comment: Equivalently those are the numbers $ a \in \{1, \ldots, 14\}$ such that $a\nmid 15$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of an element $a^k$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ equals $\frac{n}
{{\gcd (n,k)}}$.

Comment: quick question, the elements in C_12 that would have the highest order would be the prime numbers between 0 and 11 right? So elements $1, a^1, a^5, a^7, a^{11}$ would be of highest order in $C_{12}$ right?

Comment: @snowman $1$ has order $0$... But indeed the elements of $C_{12}$ with maximal order ($12$) are the powers wich belong to $\mathbb Z_{12}^\times = \{1, 5, 7, 11\}$

Comment: Definitely; if $k$ is relatively prime to $n$ then $a^k$ is a generator and that is why the number of generators in a cyclic group equals $\phi (n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $C_{12} \simeq \mathbb Z_{12}^+$, via the discrete logarithm to base $a$. The task is now to find the order of $2$ in $\mathbb Z_{12}^+$. This order is the same as the order of $a^2$ in $C_{12}$.

I'm sure you can find the order of $2$ in $\mathbb Z_{12}^+ = \{0, \ldots, 11\}$ with addition modulo $12$ and neutral element $0$ on your own.

Comment: I don't get it. OK C_12 is isomorphic to Z_12, but how do we work out a^2? Do you mean we do the method I did at the start? So since a^2 has power 2, we find the smallest n such that 2^n=1?

Comment: order of 2 in Z_12 would be very large right? because I tried it for up to 2^12, and non of them were 1...

Comment: The group operation is ADDITION ;) The order of $2$ in $\mathbb Z_{12}$ is thus $6$.